Как называется специальный веб-сайт, где бы я мог поделиться инженерным опытом в формате карточек, чтобы привлечь внимание работодателей?
Я ищу зарубежный ресурс, аналогичный Trello и Notion, на котором бы мог поделиться своим опытом для привлечения внимания работодателей на удаленные или постоянные позиции с возможностью создания «карточки с опытом работы» на информационной панели, включая, например, такие поля, как:

годы рабочего стажа;
поле для навыков, характеристик;
проекты или направления, в которых потенциально хотел бы работать/уже работал.

Как показано в примере ниже:

Причина, по которой я здесь спрашиваю, заключается в том, что я уже где-то видел подобный ресурс, но на тот момент он показался мне нерепрезентативным, поэтому я не додумался его сохранить, он был на тот момент слаборазвит.
Заранее спасибо за Вашу помощь и потраченное время.

Гляньте xing, monster
